# Show COUNT = 0 for an ID that doesn't exist in table

Tags: sql

I need to count all exams for a company and if that company don't exists in exams table, return 0.

In my Company table I have 3 companies. Here is my query:

```
SELECT c.name, ISNULL(COUNT(e.ID), 0)
FROM Exam e
INNER JOIN Company c ON c.ID = e.COMPANY_ID
GROUP BY c.name
```

It returns 2 rows, but I want to show the third company that don't have any records in exam table.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use left join instead of inner join

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a RIGHT or a more common LEFT JOIN:

```
select
  c.name,
  COUNT(e.COMPANY_ID)
from
  Company c left join Exam e
  ON c.ID = e.COMPANY_ID
group by
  c.name
```

a left join will return all records from the left table `Company`, and only the records from the `Exam` table that have a match. Count will count all non-null values.